# Copy and Paste in a column in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Suppose I have data in Notepad++ like this:

```
123                                                                         
342                                                                          
456                                            
789        
101        
102
```

and I want to edit it by copying data from row 4 to row 6 at one time and paste it in column like this rather than pasting in a single row.

```
123 789     
342 101      
456 102
```

Any help will be grateful

Answer (score 38):

1. Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow keys</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + mouse selection to select the rows you want to move.
   To quickly select several rows (lines), place the cursor at the beginning of the starting line, then hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and click the end of the last line - make sure the selection covers the entire length of all selected lines.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to cut the selected text
3. Place the cursor in the column you want to paste to and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

**EDIT:** Please note that **the content you want to paste needs to come from Notepad++, copied using Column Mode** (thanks to user @Dominique in the comments).

This will provide the result you want.

Comment: One thing which is also very important: the thing you want to paste, needs to come from Notepad++, copied using Column Mode. (I've been trying copying a range from MS Excel and it did not work: I needed to copy the Excel cells into a new Notepad++ file and copy those lines in column mode and only then I could paste them in column mode).

Comment: I was struggling to achieve that, remembering I used to be able to do it. The trick was as stated to COPY USING COLUMN MODE

Comment: Thanks for adding the 'EDIT', that was driving me crazy.