# notepad++ - copy multiple line from excel to notepad++ in the same range

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++

**I do some function in excel, and it took about 250.000 rows,
so my memory was ran out, my excel is not responding,
I try to find other way, so I need to combine it with notepad++**

I have data in excel in 5 rows, for example, like

```
A (it is a function)
B
C
D
E
```

and I have data in notepad++, for example, like

```
My score was
My score was
My score was
My score was
My score was
```

I need to achieve this

```
A My score was A
B My score was B
C My score was C
D My score was D
E My score was E
```

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: It's not a job for Notepad++, you can't apply changes with 2 files. You should write a script in your favorire scripting language.

Comment: hmmm, so sad... :( oke @Toto thank you. I have to find another why... I just found out 1 method, unfortunately it's just work for the same word, A A A A A, not A B C D E. >>> block the column in notepad++ using alt+shift+left click and then just type "A".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Notepad++ does the job. Letters are selected in column mode (`Alt` key is hold), then copied and pasted into the target file where the cursor at the target position is located in column mode (`Alt` key is hold)

Please refer to the answer

[Pasting values in column mode using Notepad++](https://superuser.com/a/1110760/1168659)

And, also note that the letters have to be transported into another Notepad++ file.

Comment: wow, thanks, one thing that I didn't know was ... Letters are selected in column mode (Alt key is hold) thank you bro

Comment: you are welcome. glad to hear that worked.